# Showing or refuting that two monic irreducible polynomials are coprimes.

Tags: polynomials, field-theory

Let $F$ field and $p(x),q(x)\in F[x]$. If  $p(x)\neq q(x)$ are monic and irreducible polynomial. Why $p(x),q(x)$ are coprimes?

I have this:  Assume that $(p(x),q(x))\neq 1$. Because $(p(x),q(x)):=d(x)$ divides $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ then $p(x)=d(x)s(x)$ and $q(x)=d(x)r(x)$ some $s(x), r(x)$.

$p(x)$ irreducible implies that $d(x)$ unit or $s(x)$ unit

$q(x)$ irreducible implies that $d(x)$ unit or $r(x)$ unit

If $d(x)$ unit then $d(x)=d$ some $d\in F^{*}$

therefore $p(x)=ds(x)$ and $q(x)=dr(x)$

but I don't know what else I can do with this

analogously, if $s(x)$ unit and ($d(x)$ unit or $r(x)$ unit)

$s(x)=s$ some $s\in F^{*}$ invertible therefore
$p(x)=sd(x)$ and $q(x)=dr(x)$ or $q(x)=d(x)r$ some $d,r\in F^{*}$

but I don't know what else I can do with this too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $d$ is not a unit, then it divides $p$, hence $d = p$. Similarly, it divides $q$, hence $d = q$ which is a contradiction. Therefore, $d$ is a unit and applying the division algorithm there are polynomials $r, s$ such that $rp+sq = d$. Divide by $d$ to get $1$ as a linear combination of $p, q$.